# Hand operated can sealer

Tags: equipment, canning

Do hand operated can sealing machines work as well as commercial automatic machines in terms of seal quality and storage life?

[image: Example hand operated can sealer]

Keen to give it a go, but can't locate any hand can sealing machines. Are there any suppliers of these that ship outside of North Amercia for order less than $1000?

Answer (score 3):

It's called a dry pack canner and the hand crank's seal just as well as the motorized versions. Electric ones go faster and your arm doesn't get as tired.

They are very expensive, especially if you are wanting to seal #10 cans.
http://www.storeitfoods.com/page/drypack